# iMac running Windows 7 - sound problems intermittently

Tags: windows-7, mac

On an iMac running Windows 7 a customer has an odd problem.  They can run media player to play music ok initially but after a period Windows will start to report that there is a problem with the sound devices and no sound will play until the machine is rebooted.

I used the latest boot camp drivers on the build.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing Realtek audio drivers, as [this](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/26/how-to-get-sound-working-in-windows-7-running-via-boot-camp/) article suggests. It might seem strange to install Realtek drivers, but Apple uses an audio chipset from that company. It might just make the problem go away.

Comment: @Chris let me know how it works, I'm actually curious myself.

Comment: Thanks. So far it seems to be working - at the very least it's more stable than it was as the things that broke the sound previously don't seem to be an issue now.